# Best practise in Android Util classes

Tags: java, android, static, singleton

What is the best practise to create android util classes?
Is it better to create static methods or normal methods with a singelton or something else? The classes should be reusable.

normal method with a singelton:

```
public class KeyboardUtils {

    private static final KeyboardUtils instance = new KeyboardUtils();

    private KeyboardUtils() {}

    public static KeyboardUtils getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }

    public void focusEt(final EditText et) {
        et.setOnFocusChangeListener((view, hasFocus) -> {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                hideKeyboard(view);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

static methods:

```
public class KeyboardUtils {

    public static void hideKeyboard(View view) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }

    public static void focusEt(final EditText et) {
        et.setOnFocusChangeListener((view, hasFocus) -> {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                hideKeyboard(view);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: To use singletone is best practice for programming.

Comment: Helper classes use static methods. That what you are looking for. Don't go for the singelton. Why would you need a singleton in this case?

Comment: so static for everything? But sometimes I have a memory leak using only static classes. For example for a SoundPool.

Comment: you don't need an instance of the class so a singleton would be useless

Comment: are util and helper classes the same?

Comment: That is just the naming